# Retrofit+rxjava unique request in stack

Tags: android, queue, retrofit, rx-java

The problem: How to make retrofit+rxjava request unique? For example user can click on button a lot of, and the are will be a lot of requests.
So, my point here, how to send only one request, but other, same requests, drop automatically. (There are should only one same request running at time)

Solution with booleans working(checking before you execute the task, that this task are already running), but maybe someone can suggest better, more universal solution?

Thank a lot of.

Comment: Checkout the operator amb. It should match your needs. Another way would be to limit requests  in a small period of time.

Comment: Please correct me, if I wrong, but I cannot add dynamically objects to amb after I execute observable? Or I can? Then how to do that?

Comment: Build an observable that emit observable. I think I read your question too fast and miss a point : unique request per Id. If I understand correctly, you can use groupBy operator (and group per id/request) than take(1) and flatMap your grouped observable. In this case, it should request only once per I'd.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could use `distinct()` or `distinct(Func1)`. For example, given an input box and a button, you want to take the input box value and do some network calls if the user clicks on the button:

```
TextBox text = ...
Button button = ...

button.clickObservable()
.map(e -> text.getText())
.distinct()
.flatMap(txt -> networkApi.someCall(txt))
.observeOn(uiScheduler)
.subscribe(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I use in current project.

Each request - class with custom logic. Each request has unique request id. Each request has access to HashMap that contains id and subscription class. Before start new request i checked if map already contains an id key and if is so there is two variants(depends on request specific) i could unsubscribe previous request and launch new or just ignore starting of new request.